# SQL REGEX character length issue

Tags: sql, regex

Issue is that this SQL regex evaluates a word with 3 characters only as incorrect, eventhough it is correct and REGEX is respected.

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(LB_DRIVER_NAME_LANM, '^[a-zA-ZâäãéëèéçôïîñÃÉËÈÉÇÔÏÎÑ]{2,200}+[-a-zA-Z- âäãéëèéçôïîñÃÉËÈÉÇÔÏÎÑª'']{2,200}$') 
THEN 1 ELSE 0  END
```

I tried to change the values a bit but still the same issue or I have issue with repeating characters. I would expect a correct word with 3 characters only respecting the rules to be evaluated as correct. I think it is related to these values {2,200}

Comment: This regex expects two blocks of characters. One that is 2-200 in length and another that is 2-200 in length. The rules about what characters are allowed in those blocks differs a bit, but essentially you would need at least 4 characters to pass this regex. Unrelated: This: `-a-zA-Z- ` is odd. It's essentially `a-zA-Z\- ` which is much less confusing, IMO.

Comment: As per JNevill, `{2,200}` means *at least two characters* and no more than 200 characters, and you have that twice so three letter words will always not pass this test.

Comment: The other tricky bit here is that `{2,200}+` is going to match as many of these patterns as it can until it encounters something that doesn't match at which point the second block that also allows space and hyphen characters to kick in where 2-200 characters would need to match for the `regexp_like` to pass. It might be helpful to pull up https://regex101.com and dump you regex into that. It will not only break up and explain each piece of this regex, but also allow you to put data and show if it has a match to this regex or not.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input that is valid, and one that is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

For the first character-class, it would appear that you'd want to use the *[lazy-quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching)*, ?, as opposed to the *[possessive-quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Possessive_matching)*, +.

Additionally, you have two *hyphens* within the second character-class—it's valid, just redundant.

```
^[a-zA-ZâäãéëèéçôïîñÃÉËÈÉÇÔÏÎÑ]{2,200}?[-a-zA-Z âäãéëèéçôïîñÃÉËÈÉÇÔÏÎÑª']{2,200}$
```